# Not Hilbert's basis theorem

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian

Hilbert's basis theorem tells us that $R[x]$ is Noetherian if $R$ is Noetherian. So, if every ideal $I\subset R$ is finitely generated, then every ideal $J\subset R[x]$ is finitely generated. This led me to consider the following:

**Claim**
For any ring $R$ and ideal $I\subset R[x]$, if $I\cap R$ is finitely generated as an ideal of $R$, then $I$ is finitely generated as an ideal of $R[x]$.

I suspect this is in fact false, because if it were true it would make the proof of Hilbert's basis theorem 'too easy'. So, I'm trying to come up with a counter-example. So I need a (non-Noetherian) ring $R$, an ideal $I\subset R[x]$ that is not finitely generated, with $I\cap R$ finitely generated as an ideal of $R$.

Any help in finding a counter-example is appreciated. So far I've been considering ideals of $R[x_1]=\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]$ whose intersection with $R=\mathbb{C}[x_2,x_3,...]$ are finitely generated, and haven't got a counter-example yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an ideal $J$ of $R$ that is not finitely generated, and let $I=xJ[x]$.

Then $I$ is not finitely generated as an ideal of $R[x]$ (if it were, then the coefficients of $x$ in a finite set of generators would generate $J$ as an ideal of $R$), but $I\cap R=0$ is finitely generated as an ideal of $R$.

Comment: What is $J[x]$?

Comment: The set of polynomials in $x$ whose coefficients are all in $J$.

Comment: In that case $I\cap R=J\ne 0$. Moreover it doesn't seem clear that $I$ is not finitely generated

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $xJ[x]$ (the polynomials with zero constant term and all coefficients in $J$). I’ll correct that.

Comment: Ok, so how do we show that $I$ is not finitely generated?

Comment: I did add a brief justification. Let me know if you want more details.